# How to automatically search maven repositories?

Tags: java, maven, automation, artifactory

I have a directory that contains maven artifacts. Some of the artifacts have a `pom.properties` file that I can use to fully resolve their GAV. Most don't. All the artifacts are named as `<artifact>-<version>.jar`.

I want to make a spreadsheet of maven coordinates for each jar. I have made a little python function that can derive the artifact name and version from the filenames.

```
import re

REGEX_A = re.compile(r'^([\w\.-]+?)-(\d+\.\d+[\w\.-]*)\.jar$')
REGEX_B = re.compile(r'^(.+?)-([\w\.]+)\.jar$')

# Returns (artifact, version) tuple
def parse_filename(basename):
    m = REGEX_A.fullmatch(basename)
    if m is None:
        m = REGEX_B.fullmatch(basename)
    if m is not None:
        return m.group(1), m.group(2)
    # last resort: return unversioned basename without extension
    return basename[:len(basename)-4], None
```

I can use these artifact/version pairs to lookup artifacts on Maven repo websites, but the process is tedious. How can I automatically lookup the artifact and version without going through a <strike>website</strike> browser?

I found Apache has a [Maven Search API](https://maven.apache.org/maven-indexer/search-api/) java library. It is not well documented. I'm not even sure if it's what I'm looking for. Further, I can't find information about the actual API behind it. I could go into their source code to reverse engineer it but I'm hoping there's an easier solution.

Comment: You must be working on converting an Ant project from 10+ years ago into a Maven project. I also assume all the `<artifact>-<version>.jar` files are in a `lib/` directory? This can definitely be a time-consuming process; hunting down the appropriate artifacts. Sometime attempting to locate these artifacts will not be successful. Keep that in mind. You may just have to include the dependency as a local dependency or upload it to a custom Maven repo. I would compare the JAR that you have to the one you eventually pull-down to make sure it's the same. Check the class file timestamps.

Comment: Also, [JD-GUI](https://java-decompiler.github.io/) is a nice tool to explore Java archive files. You can even view the decompiled source code and compare the contents of each JAR.

Comment: It's even worse. I am trying to build new plugins into an old Ant project with a `lib/` directory. I am working on a custom Gradle task to detect incompatible/missing dependencies for the plugin.

Comment: I can recommend to look into the examples https://github.com/apache/maven-indexer/tree/maven-indexer-7.0.2/indexer-examples of the maven-indexer project ... https://maven.apache.org/maven-indexer/ also there is this: https://github.com/mthmulders/mcs